# How does a planar balun work (ie, microstrip <-> stripline)?

Tags: rf, filter, pcb-antenna, microstrip, balun

[This document](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/swra350/swra350.pdf?ts=1702713055579) shows a planar microstrip/stripline balun to convert the balanced feed line input to feed the (unbalanced) dipole on a microstrip Yagi antenna.

**Question:** How does coupling to a tapered ground plane provide the means to convert an unbalanced line to a balanced line?

[image: yagi pcb balun]

[image: PCB balun]

(Linked [from University of South Florida](http://web.ecs.baylor.edu/faculty/baylis/eel4421/baluns-f07.pdf), but this is *not* a homework question.)

Comment: To what degree of explanation do you want -- hand-waved approximation, quantitative measurements, exact field solution/simulation?

Comment: @TimWilliams, looking for general conceptual/intuative understanding of why a taper can be a balun.   I'm not looking for math or exact measurements, just an understanding of how the coupling behavior "reflects" what would be common-mode leakage (ie, using a traditional dipole without a balun).  For example, does this act like a choke balun?  How?  Other considerations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it doesn't, not as shown here, not by my understanding of it anyway.

(Which is partial, mind; I don't have active design experience with antennas, or field simulators.  I've not seen references inconsistent with the below, at least.  Comments welcome.)

What they have, is a combination matching/balun stub, approx. λ/4 long, which affords feedline choking (stub balun) and probably some impedance matching.

A λ/4 stub acts as a balun, because the common-mode short-circuit impedance of the ground plane, at the base end of the stub, acts like an open circuit λ/4 away; this is the effect of a λ/4 transmission line impedance transformer.  Thus the dipole elements see a high impedance, and feedline currents are low.

Mind, that's not *quite* the whole story, because a λ/4 segment *in free space* is also a monopole; the ground plane dimensions matter, too (it's not an ideal short).  Thus there will be a monopole characteristic to this as well, and some amount of feedline current (at the elements, and spreading out over the plane).  Put another way: yes it's a choke, but part of that choke impedance is radiation resistance; it's not an ideal (infinite impedance) choke.  (Or we might load the transmission line with ferrite beads, to the same end, but they also have impedance: core loss.  No free lunch and all that.)  But anyway, such non-idealities are often an acceptable compromise; maybe reducing feedline current by say 20dB is good enough, or of having a similar reduction in error in the radiation pattern (the monopole mode has a radial radiation pattern which would spoil the directivity of the axially-oriented Yagi pattern).

Or at least, *it seems like that was the intent* -- but they partly to completely flubbed the dimensions; or just didn't care, or, the oversized ground plane covers it all up anyway.

So... this answer unfortunately becomes an intuitive but inexperienced (on this topic) engineer's analysis, which is nonetheless pulling seemingly-reasonable critiques against this thing, and, what *you* had hoped was an introduction to a neat little transmission line structure, is actually about almost anything *but* that.

And *I want to get to that*, but to get there, first I have to address how it's *wrong*.

See, the actual stub length is more like λ/8 -- it's 16mm long, while λ/4 is 30.6mm.  This is more understandable for the differential mode (which is relevant for impedance matching, but not balun action), because dielectric loading has a larger effect there (putting the DM length closer to, say, λ/6, maybe even λ/5).  But the common mode doesn't have as much loading -- I...don't have an estimate, but my *guess* is somewhere in the 10% range, i.e., due to PCB material being nearby, the CM stub length looks more like, say, 17, 18mm?

So it's a lot harder to say it's nearly enough for a proper λ/4 balun function.

So at last: **the taper section.**

What they have here is, more or less just a nod to the proper method, but because it's so small (~12mm!), it just, I can't see how it matters either way -- I think they were neither forced to remove nor improve it.  And that's assuming they did much if any optimization on this thing at all -- which I kind of suspect they didn't?  The fairly flat 10-15dB RL looks pretty clearly like mismatch to me, that could be easily cleared up with slightly different microstrip/stripline dimensions, say; or at least a passive L-match within the plane region.  (From what I've read, they should also be able to squeeze another, 3dB or so? from a Yagi of these rough specs, and maybe without compromising much on bandwidth even.)

What a taper section *can* do, when it's multiple λ/4s long, is afford a smooth transition between asymmetrical (unbalanced) microstrip (or shielded stripline, or coax), and the -- whatever you want to call it: dielectric-supported differential stripline (broadside coupled) without ground; symmetrical microstrip; parallel-plate transmission line; etc.  I haven't found a good (easily googleable) name for it yet, honestly.  In any case, between an unbalanced or asymmetrical structure, and a balanced (symmetrical) one.

Hand-wavingly, you can imagine it as, at first the image current from the microstrip is well contained within the margins of the ground plane, i.e. the plane is effective shielding, and the mode is unbalanced; as the plane width shrinks, a bit more and more of that image current reaches its edge, and thus projects magnetic field out into free space -- most of which is canceled out by the trace's field, but some of it wraps around both; and vice versa.  Eventually, the pair becomes symmetric, wrapping around each other equally; and by distributing the fields lengthwise (again, several λ/4s), common mode current is reduced while we transition from "un" to "bal".  The confined (differential) wave energy doesn't see a thing, conditions changed too gradually to notice; and little is coupled into the common mode for the same reason.

The exact profile of this taper, depends on the desired bandwidth.  We could taper it in hard steps, which would give transmission line modes -- peaks and valleys every λ/4 as waves constructively and destructively interfere along its length.  Consider the case where there's microstrip on wide ground plane (as shown), then a rectangular section λ/4 long, then balanced pair for unlimited length.  For some width of that intermediate section's ground backing, there will be the case that it emits, effectively, a quarter of the incident voltage as common mode voltage.  The same will be true of the intermediate-to-balanced transition, and so as a wave propagates from "un" to "bal", the two quarter CM voltages reinforce, and a full balun is had.  Conversely, at each transition, a CM wave is launched backwards, and the two transitions are 1/2 wave apart so they cancel out (meaning ~no feedline current is impressed onto the ground plane).

We can subdivide the rectangle into smaller sections, and repeat the process.  Say we do three sections, and do 1/4 Vcm per step; to a wave of double wavelength, the structure averages out to the same thing as before, but now we have its 2nd harmonic well-behaved as well!

And so on and so forth; as we continue to subdivide and smooth the outline, we can tweak the response for better balance, less radiation, etc. for wider and wider bandwidths.  Here's an article claiming, well, over 10:1 I'd say, while their interpretation of the measurements seems a bit optimistic; still, the low RL seems nice, and the amplitude balance isn't terrible. 
[Bah, Alpha O. et al. “An extremely wideband tapered balun for application in tightly coupled arrays.” 2016 IEEE-APS Topical Conference on Antennas and Propagation in Wireless Communications (APWC) (2016): 162-165](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/An-extremely-wideband-tapered-balun-for-application-Bah-Qin/c12c1881140a254a8bc50641cc2a57af9b2ebb54)  Note that their overall length is about a wavelength at 2GHz, which is also where it starts looking good.

...

A final note -- mind that my use of "wrong" is rather soft here: relative to whatever design principles I've picked up on this topic.  Again, I've not done designs myself, so I'm just picking at ideas here.  I'm also not claiming this post as highly factual, for this reason.  Mind even further, design principles are just that, things you can do, or patterns that repeat often enough to seem useful, but *the final arbiter is how it measures.*  On the upside -- the outward effect of such discrepancies, reduces to just feedline current, radiation pattern, and impedance mismatch.  And, I suppose, suboptimal overall dimensions (that ground plane section is huge..!).